# Performance drop: forked code Vs. openmp code

Tags: multithreading, performance, fork, openmp

I have parallel code using fork() to "read & convert grayscale images to binary". I converted the code to a multithreaded code, using openmp. But, I notice that the openmp code gives poor performance when compared to the code using fork. I initially suspected that, it could be the openmp overhead and hence tried directly using pthreads. But I notice the same pattern. Execution time of pthreaded code is also higher compared to forked code.(note: pthreads slightly better than openmp by few microseconds only)

Here are the execution times, under identical conditions.

```
+-----------------+-------------+--------------+
| No. of children | using fork  | using openmp |
+-----------------+-------------+--------------+
|              20 | 1.3         | 1.6          |
|              50 | 1.6         | 2.2          |
|             100 | 2.7         | 3.7          |
|             150 | 3.7         | 5.3          |
|             200 | 4.5         | 7.1          |
|             250 | 6.0         | 9.0          |
|             600 | 15.2        | 22.06        |
+-----------------+-------------+--------------+
```

**Edit:** added code. Compiler: gcc-4.8.5, No. of CPUs: 256

**function being called by below 2 codes:**

```
void imgProcess(char* nam){
  Pix *pixg = pixRead(nam);      
  Pix *pixb, *pixgray;
  pixgray = pixConvertRGBToGray(pixg,0.33,0.33,0.34);
  pixSauvolaBinarizeTiled(pixgray, 8, 0.34, 1, 1, NULL, &pixb); 
  pixDestroy(&pixg);    
  pixDestroy(&pixb);    
}
```

**Code using fork():**

```
int main() { 

  char prefix[60]="/root/Test/img_";  
  struct timespec i1, i2;
  long long elapsed;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &i1);  

  int count = 200;
  for(int i=0; i<count; i++){   
      if(fork() == 0){
        char filname[60];
        sprintf(filname,"%s%d%s",prefix,i,".jpg"); 
        imgProcess(filname);
        exit(0);
      }
  }    

  for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    wait(NULL); 


  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &i2);
  elapsed = i2.tv_sec*1000000000LL + i2.tv_nsec - i1.tv_sec*1000000000LL - i1.tv_nsec;
  cout<<"Total : "<<(double)elapsed/1000000000LL<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**Code using openmp:**

```
int main() { 
  int count = 200;
  omp_set_num_threads(count);

  char prefix[60]="/root/Test/img_";  
  struct timespec i1, i2;
  long long elapsed;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &i1);

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int j=0;j<count;j++){ 
      char filname[60];
      sprintf(filname,"%s%d%s",prefix,j,".jpg");         
      imgProcess(filname);
  }


  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &i2);
  elapsed = i2.tv_sec*1000000000LL + i2.tv_nsec - i1.tv_sec*1000000000LL - i1.tv_nsec;
  cout<<"Total : "<<(double)elapsed/1000000000LL<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Even if I accept that, beyond some number, forks() will be faster than threads, according to to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1808736/1554508), I still don't think they will be faster by several seconds.

**Additional information:** I did two small tests.

1. *First test:* Instead of having the imgProcess() function above as a
   unit of work, I now have a simple "time wasting for loop" as a unit
   of work for parallel jobs and noticed that openmp and forked code
   have almost similar timings.
2. *Second test:* Instead of having the imgProcess() function above
   as a unit of work, my unit of work for the parallel job is "read
   text file" using C++ stream. Timings for openmp code and forked
   code are similar in this case too.

   ```
   +---------+-------+--------+
   | threads | fork  | openmp |
   +---------+-------+--------+
   |      20 | 0.018 | 0.008  |
   |      50 | 0.04  | 0.01   |
   |     100 | 0.08  | 0.04   |
   |     150 | 0.11  | 0.03   |
   |     200 | 0.16  | 0.07   |
   |     250 | 0.19  | 0.08   |
   +---------+-------+--------+
   ```

**Questions:**

1. I was under the impression that threads and forks should have similar runtime. Any ideas of finding out why the multithreaded code behaves
   different under different cases ?
2. Until now, I just replaced the fork() part with threads. There is
   actually a scope for parallelizing gray-to-binary image conversion
   algorithm itself, which I haven't done yet. Seeing the above timing,
   I get a feeling that it may not be of use to go ahead with
   parallelizing the algorithm. What do you suggest me? Do you feel it
   may be of any use to parallelize?

Comment: You'll need to show a [mcve] that demonstrates this.  First thoughts suggest cache-line aliasing or false sharing, but without code, that's pure speculation.

Comment: Your code appears to include reading the files from disk - that could easily dwarf the processing times if you have 600 processes contending for disk I/O - although it's hard to tell because you don't show your processing code.

Comment: The processing code is an API call(leptonica image processing library) and moreover, though the files are read from disk, the situation is the same for both openmp code as well as forked code.