# What is normal practice of stopping threads that do long operations?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe2

Lets say I am about to close application/stop service, but one of my threads is going a long operation that I have no control of (lets say thirty party component is used). What is normal practice of stopping threads that do long operations? Windows service doesn't like long operations (when I click Stop button).

Comment: You don't stop threads. You signal to them to stop, and then they periodically check for that signal and then stop.

Comment: Or even better: they wait for some event using for example wait conditions or system events (so to only wake up when needed). Force kill a thread can cause the whole process to be unstable (especially if the thread operate on system resources like files, sockets, memory allocations, etc.)

Comment: "*Windows service doesn't like long operations (when I click Stop button)*" - that is not true. Services can take as long as they want to stop, provided that they actively report a stop-pending status to the SCM at regular intervals until the operation is finished. Where this becomes an issue is during system shutdown. If a service takes a long time to shutdown, Windows will kill the service.

Comment: "*lets say thirty party component is used*" - if the component doesn't provide a way to cancel a long operation in progress, then I would suggest looking for a different component that does.

Comment: Welcome in the world of "_you can't have everything_" - if the component does not fit your needs (anymore) then program it yourself. That should also make the svc more robust than to just have yet another remix of blackboxes (speak: using frameworks/components with only little own code).

Comment: 'Windows service doesn't like long operations (when I click Stop button)'  if you stop a service with running threads, Windows gives the service about 20 seconds to commit suicide.  If that limit is exceeded, the OS stops all the service threads and deletes all tbe service resources, ie. it gets murdered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10312871/758133

Answer (score 0):

> one of my threads is going a long operation that I have no control of (lets say third party component is used).

That's a deep problem. You are asking for a world of trouble if your threads don't *cooperate* with each other. The problem with killing a thread is, you have no way of knowing what the thread was doing at the moment it was killed. You could kill it while it was in the middle of allocating an object from the heap, and that could leave the heap corrupted. Your program soon would crash. You could kill it while some mutex was locked, and the next thread that tried to lock the same mutex would hang.

IMO: the best way out of the box you're in would be to perform that "long operation" in a separate process. It's much easier to design a process that can be safely killed.

Comment: But please only as a last resort - the downside of the "Chromium" approach (many processes at once) is, that each process hogs resources on its own and needs its CPU share. It's also easy to just buy more RAM and a faster CPU, sure, but even then you hit limits.

Comment: @AmigoJack, OP said, "long running..." We don't know how long exactly, but apparently it's long enough that OP can't afford to just let it go until it finishes of its own accord. To me, that sounds like, long enough so that the overhead of starting and stopping it is not a big concern. OK, I don't know Delphi, so maybe you know something I don't know: How does spinning up an extra process to do some "long running" job use significantly more CPU cycles than spinning up an extra thread within an existing process to do it?

Comment: [Threads are intended to share memory with its process and don't need their own in/out/err pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Processes). Processes are isolated from each other and each load/init dozens of libraries. Practically nowadays too many factors come into play, including [language](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/405478) and [OS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17100463/4299358) to prove this concept.

Comment: @AmigoJack, I can write a program that creates a new process, and waits for the new process to do some useful thing and terminate, and it all happens in a blink of an eye. The OP hasn't responded to comments, so I can only guess what they meant when they said, "threads that do long operations." I _guess_ that they meant an operation that takes significantly longer than a blink of an eye. So, if putting it in its own process only adds an extra eye-blink's worth of CPU time, that _might_ not deter them from doing it that way.